# Cannot connect to my local dockerized spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, docker

So I'm trying to run my Application in a docker, local on my windows machine.
The application is starting on the docker without any problems but when I try to access the API via Postman I get a connection Refused error. Note that I get no error message in the spring boot logs.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/user 
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
```

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG ARG_VERSION

ENV ENV_VERSION=$ARG_VERSION

WORKDIR /workdir/

COPY ./target/example-$ARG_VERSION.jar /workdir/example-$ARG_VERSION.jar

CMD java -jar example-$ENV_VERSION.jar
```

My docker-compose like this

```yaml
services:
  java-app:
    depends_on:
      - my_database
    container_name: java-app
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ARG_VERSION: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  my_database:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "my_database"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pw"
    restart: always
```

And my application.yml like this

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/my_database
    username: "root"
    password: "pw"

  jpa:
    database: MYSQL
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        connection:
          charSet: UTF-8
    open-in-view: true

  flyway:
    locations: classpath:/database/
    baseline-on-migrate: true
```

Comment: What does the console output of your java app say? docker-compose logs java-app

Comment: Why are you disabling Docker networking?  What "kind" of Docker are you using (Docker Desktop, Docker Toolbox, something else)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am using docker desktop

Comment: @FrankWilson that's the thing it doesn't give me any logs at all about the call

Comment: remove the network_mode. Then try again. Look at the logs and if they're odd report them here

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I need the network_host because without it my app cannot connect to the dockerized database

Comment: Remove it, and change your connection URL to reference the service name, my-database, rather than localhost